# Can I use Youtube Free Audio Library music in my online video editor?

Tags: copyright, youtube

I made an online video editor (website) and I want to let users to use music from youtube free audio library in their videos. For make it possible I need to display list of music for users, download all music files on my server and use music files with ffmpeg utility to make mp4 file. I'm interested only in music that doesn't required attribution.

Youtube copyright isn't clear about that. Can I legally do this or not?

Youtube Audio Library URL: https://www.youtube.com/audiolibrary/music

Answer (score 2):

Youtube is very clear on their usage policy;

> Music from this library is intended solely for use by you in videos
>   and other content that you create.

Futhermore, when you download the music from their library. You agree that you will not make it available in any form or anything other than your own creations.

Here is the exact text they use regarding their music library.

> Your use of this music library (including the music files in this
>   library) is subject to the YouTube [Terms of Service](https://www.youtube.com/t/terms). Music from this
>   library is intended solely for use by you in videos and other content
>   that you create. You may use music files from this library in videos
>   that you monetize on YouTube.
>
> By downloading music from this library, you agree that you will not:
>
> - Make available, distribute or perform the music files from this    library separately from videos and other content into which you have
>     incorporated these music files (e.g., standalone distribution of
>     these files is not permitted).
> - Use music files from this library in an illegal manner or in       connection with any illegal content.
>
> Additionally, some music files from this library may be subject to
>   additional requirements as set forth in the library (e.g., attribution
>   requirements). You agree to comply with such requirements when you use
>   music from this library.